# How to order by discount columns with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have MySQL columns `price` and `discountPrice` and I need to be able to sort products by `price` and also:

```
IF discountPrice is NOT empty AND is NOT NULL AND is LESS THAN price
order product by discountPrice
```

Is this somehow possible?

Comment: What does it mean for a price to be "empty"?  Surely, you are not storing numeric data as a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can put such logic in the `order by`.  Assuming `discountPrice` is numeric, this simplifies to:

```
order by (case when discountPrice < price then discountPrice else Price end)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT your_columns 
,case 
 when discountPrice < price
  then discountPrice
   else price    
    end as final_price

FROM your_tables

WHERE final_price IS NOT NULL

ORDER BY final_price ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
ORDER BY discountPrice/price DESC
```

The value for NULL will check the SQL Server itself